error while executing create token account instruction
 const sleeperAccountInstruction = await program.methods
   .createNewSleeper("test")
   .accountsPartial({
     payer: account,
     mint: mintPDA,
     sleeperAccount: sleeperPDA,
     tokenAccount: tokenAccount,
   })
   .instruction();

 const blockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

 const transaction = new Transaction({
   blockhash: blockhash.blockhash,
   feePayer: account,
   lastValidBlockHeight: blockhash.lastValidBlockHeight,
 }).add(sleeperAccountInstruction);

 console.log("signature", transaction);

 const response = await createPostResponse({
   fields: {
     type: "transaction",
     transaction: transaction,
   },
 });


signature a7 {
  signatures: [],
  feePayer: aL [PublicKey(Ci4oN3oLbaQLUpvbFuDmkW1347yJCkB7mdX8B62KnYQr)] {
    _bn: <BN: adf5aa51ea015a3938d9a19e956ff2b89fd96b3dae6ec70df1bf060788fae1cb>
  },
  instructions: [
    a5 {
      keys: [Array],
      programId: [aL [PublicKey(13go66PaZfF5vMYAKhvq5tRbcAmcEEiS8eLeqJnwkokF)]],
      data: <Buffer 6e 5f bd fd 6e 9d 22 0d 04 00 00 00 74 65 73 74>
    }
  ],
  recentBlockhash: '257MUXV4U24mVmkjcvYJmL7xyrPkMvp7CfCkD3Uegkbn',
  lastValidBlockHeight: 323085222,
  nonceInfo: undefined,
  minNonceContextSlot: undefined,
  _message: undefined,
  _json: undefined
}


i am executing this code through idl, the problem is when i execute it returns 1 error
I tried running the test in the program and it was successful, the transaction was recorded.
I really don't know where the mistake is, can anyone help me?

what error are you getting?

WalletSendTransactionError: Unexpected error

can you skip preflight checks and share the tx hash?

I have shared the code again, please help me

If you are sending the tx using the rpc method change it to this .rpc({skipPreflight: true}); and share the response to that.

one other error , SendTransactionError: Unknown action 'undefined'. :(((

Program logged: "Instruction: CreateNewSleeper"> Program logged: "AnchorError caused by account: mint. Error Code: AccountNotInitialized. Error Number: 3012. Error Message: The program expected this account to be already initialized."> Program consumed: 4865 of 199700 compute units> Program returned error: "custom program error: 0xbc4"

tx: 2UNMrBeUAteYLgF4cAqb46jdNQgikavwSUM5bmQJfYvSvLNZwaUfsUsezRKu3JkHyG4pnw2j2zJTinis8Xx6Eix

According to the transaction ID you provided, the mint account isn't initialized and that's why it's failing.
> Program logged: "Instruction: CreateNewSleeper"
> Program logged: "AnchorError caused by account: mint. Error Code: AccountNotInitialized. Error Number: 3012. Error Message: The program expected this account to be already initialized."
> Program consumed: 4865 of 199700 compute units

